# How to convert DateTime to Duration in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have trouble to convert input like 72:46:00.15768  to duration like 4366 minutes

I tried this but return null after trying the .inMinutes()

```
var _lastConso = lastConsoString3!=null ? DateTime.parse(lastConsoString3) : DateTime.now(); 
Diff = DateTime.now().difference(_lastConso);
DurationDiff=Diff.inMinutes;
```

Comment: `print(Duration(hours: 72, minutes: 46).inMinutes);` - as you can see `inMinutes` property works just fine

Comment: 72:46:00.15768 is my variable Diff. I can only manipulate Diff,

Comment: `print(Diff); print(_lastConso);` ?

Comment: what is the log output?

Comment: Diff =72:46:00.15768  
  _LastConso=2019-1205 07:33:00.000

I search to have diff =  4366

Comment: and if you try `print(Diff.inMinutes)` it does not work saying that `Diff.inMinutes` is null? what exactly `print(Diff.inMinutes)` shows on the logs?

Comment: When did  print(Diff.inMinutes); I have [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'int' has no instance method 'call'.  Receiver: 4408

Comment: `var inThePast = DateTime.parse('2019-12-02 07:33:00.000');
  var now = DateTime.now();
  var diff = now.difference(inThePast);
  print(diff);
  print(diff.inMinutes);`

Comment: It's ok thank you, the problem come from a previous code... :(

Comment: i dont understand, what previous code? did you use `print(Diff.inMinutes())` maybe?

Comment: it was the same calcul but not the same origine. this previous code search to do the same things but with MAX date gap  that I have extract from my list of date. I have output like  72:46:00.15768 who is my MAX date and i tried to convert MAX.minutes but I have the Error. Problem I can't use DateTime.now() because to convert in duraction because MAX isn't refered to now()

Comment: I use you max calcul    var prevElem = dateList2.first;
      max = dateList2.fold(Duration.zero, (maxDiff, e) {
        var diff = e.difference(prevElem); prevElem = e;
        return diff > maxDiff? diff : maxDiff; });
      print(max);

Comment: I have max date output 72:46:00.15768 but I have error when I write  max.inMinutes

Comment: if `max` is a `Duration` object and is not `null` it will work just fine

Comment: what you see if you try `print(max.runtimeType)`?

Comment: It's OK now, I don't understand what I did ^^ but all works now thank you for the help !!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 /// 72:46:00.15768
var lastConsoString3= Duration(hours:72,minutes: 46,seconds: 00,milliseconds: 15768);

var _lastConso =DateTime.now().subtract(lastConsoString3); 

var diff = DateTime.now().difference(_lastConso);
print( diff.inMinutes); /// 4366 your answer
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your variable that named `lastConsoString3` not well formatted for DateTime. Below code works fine. And you need to write var or exact type of variable.

```
var _lastConso = DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: -12)); //your parsed date
var diff = DateTime.now().difference(_lastConso);
var durationDiff = diff.inMinutes;
```